# Web browser that creates independent sessions for each new window?

Tags: windows, web-browser, internet

Is there an internet browser for a Windows PC (or can a browser be configured in such a way) where **each** New Window creates an **independent** session free of any cookies and such opened in other Windows?

Basically, how incognito mode works in Chrome, but with the ability to open *unlimited* (or *several*) independent sessions instead of just 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although Yisroel Tech's answer of "Ghost Browser" does do what I was looking for, the free version is limited to only 3 sessions.

I ended up finding a better solution that gives you **unlimited** sessions for **free**:

https://www.SessionBox.io

Comment: Great option indeed! When I recommended Ghost Browser it still didn't have that limitation.

Answer (score 4):

**Ghost Browser** might be what you are looking for. It is a Chrome-like browser with special **Multi-Session Browsing**.

While it does not open a new session for each new window, you can have as many sessions you want even in the same window. It has color coded tabs for each session.

You can download it from their site:
https://ghostbrowser.com/#features

And this is how they describe this feature:

> **Multi-Session Browsing**
>
> Say goodbye to the inefficient methods of using
> browser profiles, multiple browsers or browser extensions with bad
> interfaces just to log in to a web site with multiple different
> accounts.
>
> The multilogin capabilities of Sessions are the solution you’ve needed
> the whole time and the only one you’ll ever need again.
>
> Sessions are color-coded tabs that have isolated cookie jars so you
> can handle multilogin with ease – in one browser window. You can even
> name the Sessions to help you stay even more organized!
>
> Once you start using Sessions, you’ll wonder how you ever lived
> without it.

---

If you want to use Chrome, there is a workaround but is isn't that easy to use.

You use the following command to open a new temp profile of Chrome which is completely a separate session:

```
chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:\temp\1"
```

But each time you will need to change the directory to be 2, 3, 4 etc.

Answer (score 0):

I used [Green Browser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GreenBrowser) for that back in 2007.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's outdated theme but if someone is looking for a software for managing multiple accounts, try **GoLogin** https://gologinapp.com It has 10 day free trial.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox Addon [Temporary Containers](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/temporary-containers/).

Basically, disposable independent tabs.